# How do you input a string of a specific length?

Tags: c++, string

Let's say I were to allow the user to input `n`. They would then be able to input a string that must have `n` characters. I don't want to use a loop because the string must be on one line.

Would there be a way to do this?

This format is what I would prefer.

```
int n;
cin >> n;

string test;
cin >> test[n];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Look at the overloads of `istream.get()` and `istream.getline()` which are intended for reading into `char[]` arrays. Read the number, allocate a `char[]` or `string` of that length, then read into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could truncate whatever they input to the first n many characters.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int n;
std::cin >> n;

std::string test;
std::cin >> test;
test = test.substring(0, n);
```

You could also test the validity of their input, and prompt them to re-enter it if they enter too many characters.

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

std::string test
do
{
    std::cin >> test;
}
while(test.length() > n)
```